# Creating regular expression with sub sequences of strings

Tags: regular-expressions, strings

I am creating a program which searches for particular  types of strings. The alphabet of these strings are in $\{a, b, c\}$, for which every sub string of length 3 contains exactly $c$. Some strings that follow these constraints are:

$cabcbbca$, $cbb$ and $acaacb$

And strings that don't follow the constraints are:

$aaac$, $ccc$ and $cbcaac$

From this, I can see that a regular expression might need to be made to search for strings that follow the constraints.

I have tried hard coding some regular expressions such as:

$((a \cup b)(a \cup b)c)^*$, which would cover strings like $abcabcabc$, but will obviously not work for all strings, as their are many combinations the strings could be in.

I'm not sure how I could create a general regular expression that could strictly follow any sub string of length 3 to contain exactly one $c$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're very close - your current regular expression works fine for the middle of the string, but imposes extra restrictions end the ends - it forces non-empty strings to start with 2 non-$c$ letters and end with a $c$. How can you modify it to remove these restrictions?

Comment: You could start with a finite automaton (NFA for example) and convert it into the corresponding regexp.

Comment: Do you mean that every sub string of length 3 should have **exactly** one **c**? Your example of **aaac** not being part of the language seems to indicate this. And are strings of length less than 3 allowed?

Comment: @AcId Strings less than length 3 are by default apart of the language. Only substrings of length 3 or more need to be considered, so sub strings like `cc` are valid.`accc` would fail because of `ccc`, which is a sub string of length 3 that contains more than one `c`. All sub strings of length 3 can only contain one `c`.

Comment: @RoadRunner But are all sub strings of length three **required** to have one `c`, i.e. are strings such as `abab` and `abbb` allowed?

Comment: If all sub strings of length 3 are required to have one `c`, then `abab` and `abbb` would not be allowed. Basically if you have a string like: `cabcbbca`, and you generate all the substrings of length 3: `cab, abc, bcb, cbb, bbc, bca`, you can see that they all have only one `c`, so this is a valid string. Otherwise if one of those subtrings did not contain exactly one `c`, then it would fail.

Comment: But I still don't think you have answered my question. In your post you state "every sub string of length 3 have only one **c**"; is "only one **c**" to be interpreted as "at most one **c**" or" exactly one **c**"? As i find the statement "has only one **c**" to be ambiguous.

Comment: Only one `c` = Exactly one `c`. I apologise if that was ambigious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regular language should match your specification. I've used a slightly different notation than yours, denoting $(a \cup b)$ as $\{a,b\}$.

$\mathcal{L} = c \cup c \{a,b\} \cup c \{a,b\} \{a,b\} \cup \{a,b\} \cup \{a,b\}\{a,b\} \cup \left( ((\{a,b\}c) \cup c)? (\{a,b\}\{a,b\}c)*\right)$

$?$ denotes repetition  zero or one time, and $*$ repetition zero or more times.

It can be written in a more compact representation as:
$\mathcal{L} = c\{a,b\}\{a,b\} \cup \{a,b\}?c?\{a,b\}? \cup (\{a,b\}?\{a,b\}?c)?(\{a,b\}\{a,b\}c)* $

Comment: Updated answer to also include the strings $c \{a,b\}$ and $c\{a,b\}\{a,b\}$.

Comment: @Evil Have removed "Edit" from the answer.

Comment: I hope you are aware that "?" is not standard operator here.

Comment: I am aware that most textbooks only include the union, concatenation and Kleene star operations. However, the `?` operator can easily be derived from these operators, i.e.$ A? = A \cup \epsilon$. Further, it was explicitly stated in the question that it was  for use in a program (which I interpret as a computer program), and I think most programming languages that incorporate regular expressions have the `?` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This supplements my NFA really well.